# No certificate matches private key

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, csr

I am trying to convert a .crt file to a .pfx file.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privkey.pem -out my.pfx -in my.crt
```

The privkey.pem file is what I got when I created the .csr file.

When I execute the above openssl command I get that error:

```
No certificate matches private key
```

Interesting thing is that for another csr I request a certificate I could export the pfx.

But for this 2nd certificate its not possible.

Of course I created both csr in separated folders...

**my.crt:**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
stuff
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**privkey.pem:**

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
stuff
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you still have this issue ? The certificates may not be in the correct order. Somehow this matters and gives you the misleading message no certificate matches private key.

Comment: I got 4 certificate files from my other company department. In which order should I add those certs?

Comment: Did you try giving them all in one command starting from intermediate crts till root certificates. I guess you can do that with -in itself

Comment: I did that:  openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privkey.pem -out my.pfx -in my1.crt
 -in my2.crt -in my3.crt -in my4.crt , but still getting same error. I guess the order of the -in parameters is not important?

Comment: No I faced similar issue and that issue was fixed based on order.